# how to restrict blob url ( ie. video saved from the api response ) in a new window and only work in that curent window

Tags: node.js, reactjs

i have a post api which gives video reponse, which iam saving to blob and created a url using URL.createObjectURL(blob) and giving that url to video src. but the problem is when i insepct it and copy the video blob url and open in a new window... its opening there also... which in my case should not happen.. how to restrict it..

````
        axios.get(URI, axiosOptions ).then(responce=>{
           
            if( responce.status == 200 ){
                const blob = new Blob([responce.data], {
                    type: "video/mp4"
                });
                setVideoBlob(blob);
                
                const videoURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                console.log("video url is:", videoURL );
                setVideoUrl( videoURL );
                
            }

        }).catch(err=>{
           
            console.log(err.message);
            setErrormsg(err.message);
        });```
````